# ios autolayout constraints to resize view for screen size

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I am new to ios development and still trying to get hang of autolayout. The problem that I am facing can be better explained with images below

[image: App on Iphone 5 screen size 4 inch]

[image: App on iphone 4 screen size 3. inch]

Now I am removing the "Login with a social network" on iphone 4. What I want is how to center the google plus icon between the "OR Label" and "Start without registering" button
and it should also resize to fit between them.

what kind of constraints does it need to achieve that. If someone can point me in the right direction that would be great help. I have been breaking my head over this entire day. Thanks.

Comment: When you say "I am removing the 'Login with a social network'", are you saying that you're doing that at runtime, or while you're designing your view in IB?

Comment: removing at runtime. http://prntscr.com/1uluj7 What i want is the space between the two arrows to increase. Instead of the bottom button going up.

Comment: OK. I've updated my answer with two approaches to handling this removal of the "Login with ..." label and updating/reapplying constraints accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

to center [g+] between [or] and [start ..] buttons:
you need to do two things.. on the storyboard:

1. select [g+] and [or]
2. select editor->pin vertical spacing

and then

1. select [g+] and [start]
2. select editor->pin vertical spacing

you should see a vertical line show up between the two objects each time. This is to indicate that that space will always be the same weather on a 3.5" or a 4" iPhone display.

I don't see why you want the g+ button to resize.. that actually goes agains the UI guidelines which instruct that different users shouldn't have different user experiences (see the reason behind why there isn't a replacement for the iOS 7.0 deprecated [sizeWithFont:minFontSize:actualFontSize:forWidth:lineBreakMode:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006893-CH3-SW2) method)

The same logic that discourages changing font sizes on labels/buttons depending on form factor etc resulting in different users having different experiences, is the same logic that would discourage you from scaling up or down your [g+] button depending on form factor circumstances as well.

Comment: He I tried what you said. This is the result on iphone 5 http://prntscr.com/1ulpdu

Comment: all what the above does is that it ensures that the distance between the three buttons remain the same.. you will have to make sure that *before* you put any of the constraints.. the button is placed in the middle.. to make sure that it is indeed in the middle.. test it in both 3.5" and 4" form factors by - on the storyboard, select the view controller enclosing the view in question - open the right bar - show the attributes inspector - for size select 3.5 and see what it looks like, then select 4.0 and see what it looks like

Comment: http://prntscr.com/1uluj7 What i want is the space between the two arrows to increase. Instead of the bottom button going up.

Comment: that one is tough.. i played around with it a bit.. and it seems like you'll have to do several things to make it work.. I strongly recommend you read [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2) tutorial before you start playing around with nsconstraints, b/c they can be counter intuitive

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get the "g+" graphic centered between the "OR" label and the "Start without registering" label, you can:

1. Add a view (that you won't really see because you'll make it transparent, but it's useful for alignment purposes) whose top constraint is linked to the "OR" label and whose bottom constraint is linked to the "Start without registering" label:
2. Then put the "g+" graphic inside that view, aligning its center vertical and horizontal constraints with its superview's.

   [image]

If you do that, the "g+" button will stay in the middle between those two labels (assuming, of course, that the "Start without registering" label has a bottom constraint to its superview, i.e. It's pinned to the bottom of the view).

In terms of resizing that button, I'd personally advise against that, if you wanted, you could, for example, remove that transparent view we created above, and just do that trick with the "g+" image/button itself. You will want to set the content size of that imageview to be "Aspect Fit" (so it doesn't get distorted).

Again, I really don't like that latter approach, but you can do it.

---

I gather that you want to remove the "Log in with social network" label at runtime. There are two approaches for that:

1. A simple approach is to create an `IBOutlet` for the height constraint for that label, e.g., `logInWithSocialNetworkHeightConstraint` and then you can do:

   ```
   self.logInWithSocialNetwork.text = nil;
   self.logInWithSocialNetworkHeightConstraint.constant = nil;
   [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
   ```
2. The alternative is to define a constraint between the "OR" label and the "g+" graphic's appropriate view. This, itself, has two possible approaches:

   - You could define this in IB, but define it with a priority less than 1000. Because the constraints for the "Login with ..." label will have higher priority, when that label is there, those constraints will take precedence. If you you remove the label:

     ```
     [self.logInWithSocialNetwork removeFromSuperview];
     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
     ```

     Then the new constraint you defined will then come into play.
   - You could alternatively remove the "Login with ..." label and then programmatically add a new constraint between the "OR" button and the "g+" graphic's view.